# admin grid form image was not upload with proper path in database

Tags: customer-grid, magento2.4.6

im trying to upload image from admin grid form,image was uploaded but not in proper path,

here is my code,

app/code/Magelearn/Customform/view/adminhtml/ui_component/mladmincustomform_customform_form.xml

```
<field name="image">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
        <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magelearn_Customform/image-preview</item>
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
        <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="mladmincustomform/customform_fileUploader/save"/>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magelearn\Customform\Api\CustomformRepositoryInterface" type="Magelearn\Customform\Model\CustomformRepository"/>
    <preference for="Magelearn\Customform\Api\Data\CustomformInterface" type="Magelearn\Customform\Model\Data\Customform"/>
    <preference for="Magelearn\Customform\Api\Data\CustomformSearchResultsInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults"/>

    <!-- <preference for="Magelearn\Customform\CustomformImageUpload" type="Magelearn\Customform\Model\ImageUploader" /> -->

    <virtualType name="Magelearn\Customform\Model\ResourceModel\Customform\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">magelearn_customform</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magelearn\Customform\Model\ResourceModel\Customform\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="magelearn_customform_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magelearn\Customform\Model\ResourceModel\Customform\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magelearn\Customform\CustomformImageUpload" type="Magelearn\Customform\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
                <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">magelearn/customform/tmp</argument>
                <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">magelearn/customform</argument>
                <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                    <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                    <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
                </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magelearn\Customform\Controller\Adminhtml\Customform\FileUploader\Save">
        <arguments>
                <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magelearn\Customform\CustomformImageUpload</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Magelearn/Customform/Controller/Adminhtml/Customform/FileUploader/Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Magelearn\Customform\Controller\Adminhtml\Customform\FileUploader;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Igorludgero\Brandlist\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Igorludgero\Brandlist\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magelearn\Customform\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magelearn_Customform::Customform');
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('image');

            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }

}
```

DataProvider.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magelearn\Customform\Model\Customform;

use Magelearn\Customform\Model\ResourceModel\Customform\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    protected $loadedData;
    protected $collection;
    protected $filesystem;
    protected $dataPersistor;
    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('magelearn/customform');
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $itemData = $model->getData();
            if ($model->getImage()) {
            $imageName = $itemData['image']; // Your database field 
            //unset($itemData['image']);
            $itemData['image'] = array(
                array(
                    'name'  =>  $imageName,
                    'url'   =>  $this->storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ).'magelearn/customform'.$itemData['image'] // Should return a URL to view the image. For example, http://domain.com/pub/media/../../imagename.jpeg
                )
            );
            }
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $itemData;
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('mladmincustomform');
        
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('mladmincustomform');
        }
        
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    
}
```

Magelearn/Customform/Controller/Adminhtml/Customform/Save.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magelearn\Customform\Controller\Adminhtml\Customform;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    //protected $imageUploader;
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data['image']); die();
        if ($data) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');            
            
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magelearn\Customform\Model\Customform::class)->load($id);

            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This Customform no longer exists.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }            

            if (isset($data['image'][0]['name']) && isset($data['image'][0]['tmp_name'])) {
                $data['image'] = $data['image'][0]['name'];
                
                /*$this->imageUploader = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                'Magelearn\Customform\CustomformImageUpload');*/
                
                /*$imageUploader = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magelearn\Customform\CustomformImageUpload::class);
                $imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($data['image']);*/

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $imageUploader = $objectManager->get(\Magelearn\Customform\CustomformImageUpload::class);                
                $imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($data['image']);

                //$this->imageUploader = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magelearn\Customform\CustomformImageUpload::class);
                //$this->imageUploader->setBasePath('magelearn/customform');

                //$this->imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($data['image']);
            } elseif (isset($data['image'][0]['name']) && !isset($data['image'][0]['tmp_name'])) {
                $data['image'] = $data['image'][0]['name'];
            } else {
                $data['image'] = null;
            }
            $model->setData($data);
        
            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the Customform.'));
                $this->dataPersistor->clear('mladmincustomform');
        
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId()]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Customform.'));
            }
        
            $this->dataPersistor->set('mladmincustomform', $data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }        
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

in the database it save path image like

> "m/a/magento-vs-shopify_1.jpg",

but need to save like

> "magelearn/customform/m/a/magento-vs-shopify_1.jpg"

not saved this path.
please hele me with this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: image not show in grid?

Comment: yes image was saved, but it does not take the proper path, but why not save it with the proper path, I don't understand that. @MufaddalDhansurawala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try Below Code**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

**attribute_logo_form.xml**

```
    <field name="logo_name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">logo_name</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Upload Logo</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="adminroutername/controllername/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/template**

**image-preview.html**

```
    <div class="actions">
        <button
            type="button"
            class="action-remove"
            data-role="delete-button"
            attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
            click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
            <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
<div class="file-uploader-meta">
    <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
</div>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

**Upload.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public $imageUploader;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('logo_name');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }

        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model**

**ImageUploader.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

class ImageUploader
{
    private $coreFileStorageDatabase;
    private $mediaDirectory;
    private $uploaderFactory;
    private $storeManager;
    private $logger;
    public $baseTmpPath;
    public $basePath;
    public $allowedExtensions;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = 'magelearn/customform';
        $this->basePath = 'magelearn/customform';
        $this->allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
    }

    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }

    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }

    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {
        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }

    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }

    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }

    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }

    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();
        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);

        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }

        return $imageName;
    }

    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));
        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
            );
        }

        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];
        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);

                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">magelearn/customform</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">magelearn/customform</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/Index**

**Save.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magelearn\Customform\Model\CustomformFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $attributeLogoFactory;
    protected $adminsession;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        CustomformFactory $attributeLogoFactory,
        Session $adminsession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->attributeLogoFactory = $attributeLogoFactory;
        $this->adminsession = $adminsession;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $postId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($postId) {
            $attrData = $this->attributeLogoFactory->create()->load($postId);
            $data = $this->updateLogoName($data, $attrData);
            $attrData->setData($data);
            $attrData->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The data is updated successfully.'));
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }

    public function updateLogoName($data, $attrData)
    {
        if ((isset($data['logo_name'][0]['error'])) && ((isset($data['logo_name'][0]['name'])))) {
            $data['logo_name'] = "magelearn/customform/".$data['logo_name'][0]['name'];
        } else {
            $data['logo_name'] = $attrData->getLogoName();
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model**

**DataProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

use VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data;
use Magelearn\Customform\Model\ResourceModel\Customform\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    protected $exAttLogoHelper;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        Data $exAttLogoHelper,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->exAttLogoHelper = $exAttLogoHelper;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $itemValue) {
            $this->loadedData[$itemValue->getId()] = $itemValue->getData();
            if ($itemValue->getLogoName()) {
                $this->loadedData[$itemValue->getId()]['logo_name'] = [ 0 => [
                        'name' => $itemValue->getAttrVal(),
                        'url' => $this->exAttLogoHelper->getLogoMediaUrl($itemValue->getLogoName()),
                    ],
                ];
            }
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Helper**

**Data.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    public const ATTRIBUTE_LOGO_PATH = 'magelearn/customform/';

    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getLogoMediaUrl($fileName)
    {
        $mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        $mediaUrl .= $fileName;

        return $mediaUrl;
    }
}
```

**In you grid component update replace column like this**

```
<column name="logo_name" class="VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">title</item>
            <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Logo</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Ui/Component/Listing/Column**

**Thumbnail.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Thumbnail extends Column
{
    const ALT_FIELD = 'title';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    protected $exAttrLogoHelper;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param Image $imageHelper
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        Image $imageHelper,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Data $exAttrLogoHelper,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->exAttrLogoHelper = $exAttrLogoHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $url = '';
                if ($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                    $url = $this->exAttrLogoHelper->getLogoMediaUrl($item[$fieldName]);
                }
                $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $url;
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] =  "alt name";
                $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    'adminroutername/conrollername/edit',
                    ['id' => $item['id']]
                );
                $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $url;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

After adding and updating above files. Please run below command :

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:s:d -f
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: in this file, in which code i need to update?

Comment: I updated in answer.

Comment: i have already done this but its not work..its save with the same path that i already ask in my question

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki I added the whole solution here. Please check it and update me if you have any questions.

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki have you checked the new update answer? is it working for you?

Comment: yes i have tried your provided updated code, i have tried without Helper file, because i have not used from starting so, but its not work. i did not understand why path was not saved as per BasePath?

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki I updated the code. please follow the above files in your module and check the image path. Now I checked on my side it's working.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference Link](https://www.magedelight.com/resources/how-to-upload-image-using-ui-component-in-magento-2/)

**Replace the Save.php file with the below code and check:**

```
<?php

namespace Magelearn\Customform\Controller\Adminhtml\Customform\FileUploader;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Igorludgero\Brandlist\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    protected $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var File
     */
    protected $fileIo;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Igorludgero\Brandlist\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param File $fileIo
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magelearn\Customform\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        File $fileIo,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->fileIo = $fileIo;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magelearn_Customform::Customform');
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('image');
            $imageName = $result['name'];
            $basePath = $this->filesystem->
                getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath() . 'magelearn/customform/';
            $mediaRootDir = $this->filesystem->
                getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath() . 'magelearn/customform/';
            $newImageName = $this->updateImageName($mediaRootDir, $imageName);
            $this->fileIo->mv($basePath . $imageName, $mediaRootDir . $newImageName);
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
            $mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->
            getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
            $result['url'] = $mediaUrl . 'magelearn/customform/' . $newImageName;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }

}
```

Comment: not working this code, even its not update the image in database.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer Below Link

- https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-upload-image-or-file-in-custom-module-using-ui-component-in-magento-2/
- https://store.magenest.com/blog/create-an-image-uploader/

Hope it will work